# SQL SERVER COUNT AND JOIN

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, join, pivot

Hi guys I'm having problems to make a query in sql server.

I have 3 tables: testcases, executions and execution_bugs:

**testcases**

```
id | name
-------------
1  | Login
2  | Logout
```

**executions**

```
id | testcase_id
-----------------
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 1
```

**execution_bugs**

```
execution_id | bug_id
----------------------
1            | B-1
3            | B-2
```

And I need to know how many testcases are defined, how many of them have been executed, how many testcases have bugs and how many do not.

I was looking for a query that would give me this kind of result:

```
testcases_n | executed | with_bugs | without_bugs | bugs_amount
---------------------------------------------------------------
2           | 2        | 1         | 1            | 2
```

Is this possible given the table structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
declare @testcases as table ( id int, name varchar(16) )
insert into @testcases ( id, name ) values
  ( 1, 'login' ), ( 2, 'Logout' )

declare @executions as table ( id int, testcase_id int )
insert into @executions ( id, testcase_id ) values
  ( 1, 1 ), ( 2, 2 ), ( 3, 1 )

declare @execution_bugs as table ( execution_id int, bug_id varchar(16) )
insert into @execution_bugs ( execution_id, bug_id ) values
  ( 1, 'B-1' ), ( 3, 'B-2' )

select
  ( select count(42) from @testcases ) as testcases_n,
  ( select count(distinct testcase_id) from @executions ) as executed,
  ( select count(distinct e.testcase_id) from @executions as e inner join @execution_bugs as eb on eb.execution_id = e.id ) as with_bugs,
  ( select count(42) from @testcases ) - ( select count(distinct e.testcase_id) from @executions as e inner join @execution_bugs as eb on eb.execution_id = e.id ) as without_bugs,
  ( select count(42) from @execution_bugs ) as bugs_amount
```

Comment: I wasn't thinking of using subqueries because I need to filter records using where statements. But let me try this and I tell you how it went. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also I'm using PHP and SQL Server -odd, I know- so I need to simplify queries.

Comment: hmmm, what is count(42) for?  and whats the difference between count(*)?

Comment: @hagensoft - `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(42)` return the same result.  For those who insist that a `SELECT` _never_ use `*`, it is calming.  Using a constant shows me that I thought about the desired result and did not want a count of non-NULL values for a specific column.  The choice of `42` is simply because it is the [Answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_to_The_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29).